# maven - java compiler version set to older version automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

For some reason maven automatically chooses java compiler 1.5 when building my project although I have jdk 1.8 installed

**Step 1**

`Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> JRE System Library -> Edit`, 
and then choose "Workspace default JRE (jdk1.8.0_102)".

**Step 2**

Just in case I also set `Eclipse -> Preferences -> Installed JREs -> JavaSE-1.8 (jdk.1.8.0_102)`

*What I noticed in that window: There is only J2SE-1.x where x<=5*

**Step 3**

Then I go to `Project -> Java Compiler, where I find the compiler compliance level set to 1.5 (see screenshot). So I change "Compiler compliance level to 1.8"

[image: java compiler settings in eclipse]

When I do maven update, everything is reset to compiler compliance 1.5. If I do a `mvn clean compile` I also get a build failure that source is 1.5 and some of my code is not compatible.

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is more of information, i also face this kind of problem  , do you want to set a newer verson manually ?

Comment: Adding the following tag will fix your issue `<properties> <java.version>11</java.version>   </properties>`

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your pom.xml file under `<plugins>`:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
```